# logrotate not working as expected with my custom log

Tags: cron, logrotate

I turned on mysql general log, and since it was growing pretty fast I thought of using logrotate daily, so I created the log yesterday at about 2pm and this is how the log looks like:

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql adm  1751348 Jun 16 11:55 general.log
```

I added a new rule to logrotate which looks like this:

```
/var/log/mysql/general.log {
daily
rotate 12
dateext
compress
missingok
notifempty
create 640 mysql adm
postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd
    endscript
}
```

And according to /etc/crontab it runs at 6:25am, but it didn't rotate my log yesterday

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

the output of running logrotate --dry-run:

```
logrotate -d general
reading config file general
reading config info for /var/log/mysql/general.log 

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/mysql/general.log  after 1 days (12 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/mysql/general.log
  log does not need rotating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated
```

What else do I have to do so it rotates my log?

Comment: if you run it by hand in one day, it wont work in the next run as 24h wont have elapsed by yet.

Comment: You can also try running `logrotate` with the `-d` flag to see what's going on.

Comment: @Kusalananda I added it in my question the output of dry run but there's nothing relevant, it just says "does not need rotating", which it was saying that yesterday so that's why I waited until today but it didn't change.

Comment: Hmm... wait a bit longer?  Also, I noticed you're using checking for `anacron`. This is unrelated, but why do you need to do that?

Comment: @Kusalananda because I wanted to know what time does logrotate run if I set my logrotate rule to daily. If that's not the place to look to know at what time does logrotate run every day then? Is there any way I can pretend that a day has passed so I can debug if there is something is not right and why logrotate is not working?

Comment: That didn't quite make sense to me, but ok. If you just want to force a rotation, use `logrotate --force`. That will tell you whether the rotation itself works.

Comment: I just realized something. If you cron job runs exactly every 24 hours, and if `logrotate` is set to rotate every 24 hours, there's a chance that the last rotation happened 23h59m and 50-something seconds ago, i.e. not a full 24 hours. The cron job should ideally be triggered hourly IMHO.

Comment: 24 hours starting what time? I guess that's what I'm trying to know. I did `logrotate -f` and yes it worked, so I guess I just have to wait a little bit longer, but the questions remains, at what time does logrotate run?

Answer (score 0):

Log rotation should probably be initiated more than once a day, probably every hour. The decision to actually rotate the logs or not should be left to the log rotation facility (`logrotate` in your case), not to `cron`.

By invoking `logrotate` once every 24 hours, the following scenario will likely happen:

- `cron` initiates the log rotation job at *X* (a time).
- `logrotate` is started, goes through its list of logs to rotate, and finishes at *X*+*n* (*n* seconds later).

24 hours later:

- `cron` initiates the log rotation job at *Y* (*X*+24h).
- `logrotate`, if it cares about seconds, notices that the logs that were rotated in the previous log rotation are not yet fully 24 hours old (there's an 1 to *n* seconds discrepancy), and skips them.